# Локальные переменные java

Tags: java

Что будет со значением переменной, если объявить её в классе (т.е. сделать переменной экземпляра), а затем присвоить значение в методе?
Вопрос в том, что сохранится ли значение переменной экземпляра в классе? То есть если значение переменной в самом классе равно 0, то при задатии значения в методе(например, 5) останется ли значение старым(равным нулю)?
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Попробуйте написать проверочную программу для вашего вопроса. Если это вызывает затруднения, то объясните, какие именно. Для меня сейчас вопрос звучит как "что будет если написать X", ответ на который "напишите X и посмотрите"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект (переменная) экземпляра класса существует в единственном экземпляре, методы могут ее изменять, читать, делать все что угодно. Метод не делает копию переменной, а работает именно с переменной класса, только если эта переменная не объявлена внутри тела метода. Если переменная статическая, то она существует в единственном экземпляре для всех экземпляров данного класса.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял ваш вопрос:

```
public class Example {
     privatу int number = 0;

     Example(int a) {
          this.number = a;
     }

     Example() {}

     public void someMethod() {this.number = 7;}
}
```

Теперь сам `main`

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
          Example e = new Example(); //number = 0!
          e.someMethod(); //number = 7
          e = new Example(9); //number = 9
     }
}
```

Весь смысл экземпляра класса и заключается в том, чтобы методы могли работать с его значением!